# Use roxygen2 to document multiple datasets in a single documentation object

Tags: r, dataset, documentation, documentation-generation, roxygen2

I'm looking for an equivalent of `@describeIn` that will allow me to create a single documentation object for multiple R data objects.

I had hoped that something like this:

```r
#' Tree Distances
#' 
#' These datasets contain the distances between sets
#' of 10-tip, 11-tip and 12-tip trees.
#' 
#' @name treeDistances
#' @keywords datasets
"treeDistances10"
"treeDistances11"
"treeDistances12"
```

would produce a single manual page that would apply to all three `treeDistances##` objects, similar to describing one function within another using `@describeIn treeDistances Distances between 11-tip trees`.

I notice that adding `@aliases treeDistance11 treeDistance12` associates the documentation page with the data objects, but without referencing the objects in the Usage section – but I believe that there is a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#multiple-man

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `@rdname`:

```r
#' Tree Distances
#' 
#' These datasets contain the distances between sets
#' of 10-tip, 11-tip and 12-tip trees.
#' @name treeDistances
#' @keywords datasets
"treeDistances10"

#' @rdname treeDistances
"treeDistances11"

#' @rdname treeDistances
"treeDistances12"
```